# Combox doesn't show added items

Tags: c#, combobox, windows-phone-8.1

I have a problem with adding comboBox items to my comboBox in my Windows Phone 8.1 app.

The following code is placed in the page_load function and step by step debugging shows that e.Name contains correct values so it's not a problem with the ElementList.

```
foreach (element e in ElementList)
            {
                ComboBoxItem cbItem = new ComboBoxItem();
                cbItem.Content = e.Name;
                cbElements.Items.Add(cbItem);
            }
```

The problem is that after the page_load function finishes, my comboBox is still empty, even though it's Count value is not 0. I really haven't got the slightest clue, why it doesn't want to fill up.

Thanks for you help

Comment: is "cbElements" the combobox ? If yes, i recommend that in any form all UI controls contain their type name, e.g. CountryComboBox, LocationTextBox. What wan't solve your problem :(

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are not binding the `cbElements.ItemsSource` property to the `ElementList` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. It's pretty dumb though, as it was a XAML related problem. A StackPanel was accidently overlapping the comboBox and as such, preventing me from clicking on it. Lesson learned though, always check if you are tapping the correct object.

I'd like to thank everyone who posted solutions and tried to help

Answer (score 1):

Try refreshing the combobox using the `Refresh` method.

`comboBox1.Refresh();`

It's possible you might need to do that since the combobox has its contents generated at runtime.

Comment: Thank you @Johnathon , couldn't have said it better

Comment: Welcome to SO; you're welcome. You want to try and be as detailed as possible when giving your answers here. You never know if the person reading the answers is brand new to development or a seasoned pro. It's best to write them so those that have never done this before can understand it clearly.

Comment: I'm fresh blood as well, thank you for the edit, it's much more clear. I'll keep a post it of your suggestions. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set the display/value member properties of the combo box for the data to display.

Looks like the property you're trying to display is "Name", so you'd probably want to set both to "Name".

```
cbElements.DisplayMember = "Name";
cbElements.ValueMember = "Name"; // or some other value if you have an ID
```

Comment: Are you sure? Because my comboBox doesn't have DisplayMember or ValueMember properties. The only one similar is DisplayMemberPath but that one doesn't work.

Comment: Oops, you're right. Try 
'cbElements.DisplayMemberPath="Name"
cbElements.SelectedValuePath="Name"'. Setting both of those might help instead of just setting the display member path.

Comment: Even if he doesn't set the `DisplayMemberPath`, the combobox should be rendering the `ToString()` of the Type he is assigning to the `ComboBoxItem`. If he is not even seeing the `ToString()`, there is something else wrong.